# Injecting $L_1$ into a Besov space

Tags: besov-space

Can someone help me to find a counter-example that proove that $L_1$ is not injected in the homogeneous Besov space $B^{0,2}_1$ ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to find a a counter-example  that proove that $ L^1 \subseteq  B^{0,2}_1 $ is false.